# Git url vs http url

Tags: git

When you want to Clone a Git Repo, you have the option of the `git://` url or the `https://` url, my question is which is faster, or does it even make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In early versions of git there was a huge difference, with `git://` being **much** faster. Since the introduction of [smarthttp](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) the difference has become so small that both are perfectly usable.

HTTPS is usually easier to get through a proxy.